Geometry Nodes: Is it impossible to make precise dimensions in this steel frame prototype method?
The goal with this node setup is to add geometry to edges and make them look like steel frames. The method bellow works well, but there's a problem, it's only precise for cubes.
Anything different from a cube, even rectilinear, gets weird offset.In the examples are 2 equal meshes at same position, one with the geometry node(black) and the other without.
My attempt was:

Retrieve the bounding box
Subtract max from
Minimum positions to get length.
Then remove the result with the steel
Frame thickness(to shrink original geometry that gets thicker with the geometry nodes)
Calculate the new scale

I've been playing with nodes to learn, and reached a roadblock. Is there any way around it?

Here's the file:


Solving this runs into the issue of defining the inside from the outside of your mesh, and since it isn't closed, this is undefinable. I'm working on a solution that would require a closed mesh, where armature would be marked by edge attributes such as 'sharp' or 'edge bevel'
